# Apply behaviour to WPF DataGrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, componentone

I'd like to attach a behaviour to a (Component One) data grid row.

The problem is: I can't get to the DataContext of the actual row. In the style my data context is the data grid..  how can I get to the row's data context?

```
<c1:C1DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="c1:DataGridRowPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ui:DataGridRowHierarchyBehavior.IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource=}" />
    </Style>
</c1:C1DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I know about how to 'get up' the visual tree using `RelativeSource` -
though how 'getting down' could work I don't have a clue..

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tired using with "ElementName = "<your component name>"  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to the DataItem of the row, you need to use RelativeSource in the Binding in the following way :

```
<c1:C1DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type c1:DataGridRowPresenter}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Row.DataItem.Background}"></Setter>
   </Style>
</c1:C1DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I've used the Background property as an example.